# How do I Dispose a HttpResponseMessage in my Web Api Method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I'm getting the [CA2000](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(CA2000);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.1)&rd=true) error on all my Wep Api 2 controllers for the Options() verb.

> In method 'PromotionController.Options()', object '<>g__initLocal0' is not disposed along all exception paths.

I need to support pre-flight requests made for cross domain ajax calls so all I'm doing is returning a `HttpStatusCode.Ok` so that the subsequent post/put/delete will fire off.

```cs
public HttpResponseMessage Options()
{
    return new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK };
}
```

I have tried the using statement like this:

```cs
public HttpResponseMessage Options()
{
    using(var response = new HttpResponseMessage())
    {
        response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        return response;
    }
}
```

but when I hit it with an Options request from Postman I get an exception:

> Cannot access a disposed object.\r\nObject name: 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage'.

How do I return the `HttpStatusCode.Ok` in a way that it won't throw Code Analysis errors?

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, and why don't you use Owin/CORS, or WebAPI CORS?

Comment: See [this previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361912/how-do-i-dispose-of-resources-after-an-asp-net-web-api-request-completes) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27715327/1260204)

Comment: @Igor I saw that post while searching but from what I can see, HttpResponseMessage doesn't support RegisterForDispose. Only HttpRequestMessage does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exception about accessing a disposed object is obvious because when execution leaves the `using` block, `response` is disposed, but you're returning it out of the `using` block and out of the method. You can't access that object outside of the method, because it simply doesn't exist anymore.

In general, to solve the *CA2000* warning simply dispose the instance of `HttpResponseMessage` class explicitly when you don't need it anymore.

In your case solution could be to **override the [`Dispose` method of your controller](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.dispose(v=vs.118).aspx)** (implements the `ApiController` method) and **explicitly dispose your instances there**. Check for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27895583/dispose-method-in-web-api-2-web-service).

You can also just suppress the warning and instance will be disposed later by the garbage collector anyway. But it's not a proper solution.

Comment: I'm hoping they'res another way because I hate suppressing warnings

Comment: Yep, I definitely agree and what I read in answers linked in Igor's comment to your question, you should have at least 2 possibilities - controller's `Dispose` method and `RegisterForDispose` extension.

Comment: @Elliott Did my answer helped you to solve your problem? If yes, can you accept it so others will be able to find the answer more easily, please? It would also allow others to mark similar questions as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: @Elliott Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can register the response object for disposing using [`RegisterForDispose`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessageextensions.registerfordispose(v=vs.118).aspx) method of `HttpRequestMessage` class. Infrastructure of .Net will disposes all registered object after disposing the request.

I can't guaranty that you won't get the error after that, but the object will be disposed so that you can suppress the error.

**Example**:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse();
// Do what you need with response
// ...
// ...
request.RegisterForDispose(response);// response will be disposed by host
```